# Is there a standard way of handling logging from an Android app?

Tags: android, logging

I haven't been able to find any good resources, tutorials, or open source libraries talking about standard ways of logging from an Android app. Is it common to send messages on a per message basis or upload log files periodically?

Ideally I would like to send messages to something like a logstash server, but this doesn't seem to be a very common approach. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean log from Android app? What kind of information are you logging? Debug/User info/Statistic/Analytic?

Comment: I mean any general logging like unexpected situations, errors, etc. Not necessarily fatal crashes but situations that were not expected to happen and we would like to know that they are occurring.

Answer (score 1):

Check [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra) in github. As they say in their [website](http://www.acra.ch/),

> Acra catches exceptions, retrieves lots of context data and send them to the backend of your choice.

Meaning you can custom it to send just the data logs you need.

Comment: Looks nice. Does it only log crashes? I was asking about general logging as well.

Comment: @rking788 You can include any data of your choice, check the "advanced usage" section. But you can just use something like ACRA.getErrorReporter().putCustomData("myKey", "myValue");

Comment: ok. that is helpful. does it only upload that info if there is a crash though?

Comment: What backend do you use for ACRA? Acralyzer  is not maintained now it seems